# How do you add math symbols in colorbar ticks

Tags: matlab, figure

I can get the `colorbar` ticks as

```
figure;
hbar=colorbar;
ticks=get(hbar,'ytick');
```

Now how do I set the tick labels at `tick(end)` to be `∞`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is tricky. Normally, for axes labels and titles you can use TeX or LaTeX formatting since they are [text objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/text.html) and thus have an [`'Interpreter'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/text_props.html#Interpreter):

```
xlabel('\infty');  %# Label the x axis with an infinity
```

However, [axes objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html) themselves don't appear to have a way to use Tex or LaTeX formatting for their *tick* labels. One solution is to download the submission [Format Tick Labels](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15986) from [Alexander Hayes](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/29071) on the [MathWorks File Exchang](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/)e, which will replace the axes tick labels with formatted text objects.

Another solution is to change the [`'FontName'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html#FontName) of the axes to the `'Symbol'` font, the 165<sup>th</sup> character of which is the infinity symbol. Here's an example:

```
hBar = colorbar;                           %# Create the colorbar
labels = cellstr(get(hBar,'YTickLabel'));  %# Get the current y-axis tick labels
labels{end} = char(165);                   %# Change the last tick label
set(hBar,'FontName','Symbol',...           %# Change the colorbar axes font
         'YTickLabel',labels);             %#   and update the tick labels
```

And here's what the colorbar will look like:

[image]

Comment: +1 nice hack with the `Symbol` font. My question: is it system-independent (does it work out of the box on Mac/Linux, or do you have to add a similar font yourself)

Comment: @Amro: The `Symbol` font has to be installed on your machine, and I'm not sure if Mac or Linux has it by default. I don't know if any fonts come pre-packaged with MATLAB (I doubt it), but you can at least find out what the available system fonts are using the function [LISTFONTS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/listfonts.html).