# Superscript tick labels for MATLAB's colorbar

Tags: matlab, figure

Similar to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463554/how-do-you-add-math-symbols-in-colorbar-ticks), I am trying to use superscripts in MATLAB's colorbar ticks.

```
figure;
hbar=colorbar;
ticks=get(hbar,'ytick');
```

The workaround in that previous scenario was to use the `symbol` font.  In my case, I am trying to let `tick(end)` be a string containing superscripts, such as `10^3`, and it seems that this workaround no longer applies.

How does one use superscripts in labels for colobar ticks?

Comment: Did you also check this link? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15986-format-tick-labels This should work.

Comment: I have tried `format_ticks(h,{'$10^3$','$10^4$'},[],[3 4])` with no effect on the colorbar.

Comment: what Matlab version are you using?

Comment: possible [solution](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/61657)?